# Eigenvalues of $A+\alpha uu^T$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A = diag \left (\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n \right ) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, with $\lambda_1 < \lambda_2 < ... < \lambda_n$.
Let $u = \left (u_1, ..., u_n \right ) ^T \in \mathbb{R}^n$, with $u_i \neq 0 \ \ \forall i$.
How can be shown that:

1. For any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}, \alpha \neq 0, \lambda_i$ is **not** an eigenvalue of $A+\alpha uu^T$.
2. The eigenvalues of $A+\alpha uu^T$ are the roots of the equation $f(\tau)=0$, where:
   $\displaystyle f(\tau)=1+\alpha \sum_{i=1}^n{\frac {u_i^2}{\lambda_i-\tau}}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $(A-\lambda_j I+\alpha\,uu^T)x=0$. We can write this as $(A-\lambda_j)x=-\alpha\,uu^Tx$. If we look at the $j^{\rm th}$ coordinate, the left-hand side is $0$, and the right-hand side is
$$
-\alpha(u^Tx) u_j,
$$
so (using that all coordinates of $u$ are nonzero) $u^Tx=0$. But then the right-hand side is $0$ in all its coordinates. For any $k\ne j$, the corresponding coordinate on the left-hand side is $(\lambda_k-\lambda_j)x_k$, so $x_k=0$.

We have thus shown that $x=0$, i.e. the kernel of $(A-\lambda_j I+\alpha\,uu^T)$ is the trivial subspace, which says that $\lambda_j$ is not an eigenvalue of $A+\alpha uu^T$.

For part 2), one only needs to notice that 
$$
\det(A-\tau\,I+\alpha\,uu^T)=(\lambda_1-\tau)\cdots(\lambda_n-\tau)\,\left(1+\alpha\,\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{u_j^2}{\lambda_j-\tau}\right)
$$
and that by part 1) the factors $\lambda_j-\tau$ are all nonzero. Indeed, this equality follows from the fact that if $B$ is $n\times n$ invertible and $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$, then
$$
\det(B+xy^T)=(1+y^TB^{-1}x)\,\det B
$$
(taking of course $B=A$, $x=y=\alpha^{1/2}\,u$).

Comment: Great job. Thanks so much Martin.

Comment: My pleasure. I had to search for the determinant identity at the end, which I didn't know about. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

try using definition for prob a.   try to find characteristic polynomial for b

Comment: Just a recommendation that it might be helpful to provide more details on this response to make what you are saying clearer. As currently written, it is very difficult to understand. Regards

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let 
$$g(\tau):=\prod_i(\lambda_i-\tau)\,\cdot f(\tau)=\prod_i(\lambda_i-\tau)+\alpha\,\sum_i\,\left(u_i^2\cdot\prod_{j\ne i}(\lambda_j-\tau) \right)\,,$$
which is a polynomial of $\tau$ (of degree $n$). By (a big amount of) hypothesis, we have that $g(\lambda_i)\ne 0$, and if we prove that the roots of $g$ are exactly the eigenvalues of $A+\alpha\,uu^T$, we're ready. I would not be much surprised if $g$ were just its characteristic polynomial.